# Flexible metal conduit touching black steel gas line

Tags: electrical, gas

I'm running a section of flex conduit through a wall that already has a 3/4" black steel gas line running through it. The hole that the gas line is run through has a good amount of extra space next to the line.  A couple of questions:

- Can the flex conduit be in contact with the gas line or does there need to be some sort of non metallic barrier between the two?
- If there has to be a barrier, is wrapping the flex conduit with electrical tape for that section enough?

Comment: Not even close to knowing, but usually you want two objects not touching if there is any chance of movement/vibration/rubbing.

Comment: @crip659 Especially when one of them can generate sparks and the other doesn't like sparks...

Comment: Give your local gas company a call. I'm sure they will _happily_ tell you what needs to be done. They'd much rather do this, than have to come out and repipe the neighborhood after an explosion. (Note: I'm not saying that an explosion _will_ happen, but that the gas co would be _the_ ones to know this stuff off the top of their heads. They'd be most happy to ensure that there are no incidents of any sort.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't recall anything in the NEC.

Don't have gas code reference but had seen gas pipes wrapped where they contacted conduits, so I once wrapped a conduit with Scotch 33 where I intersected a gas pipe. When the fitter saw it he asked if my tape was UL510? I said I didn't think so, he said don't bother, the di-electric tape has to be UL approved and he wrapped his pipe.